# google sheets filter unique values which contain a specific text

Tags: google-sheets

[Sample Code](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1djagTa5XIuaowVcrf30l0uhBT6-2I3I1zrpdJ8aDw5k/edit?usp=sharing)

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WEf6.png)

I have a google sheet with H3 having the following code:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(B3:D))
```

This code list all the unique data. However, because there are so many students, I have to scroll all the way down to find specific individual's unique entries.

I was wondering if I could create a code that looks for the value in J2 and filters the result of H3 to only show names shown on J2. However the code FILTER seems to only accept conditional formatting in numbers?

The following code does not work, so what could be an alternate code:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B3:D,B3:D == J2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(filter(B3:D, B3:B=J1)))
```

Change ranges to suit.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we have some data to work with.

Comment: J2 contains the words 'Study Counsel'. Do you want to filter on that? Can you clearly describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: J2 is the name up top, in the purple area. I would like that for whoever has their name there to be the ONLY one that will appear in H3

Comment: I believe that should be J1 instead? If so try =SORT(UNIQUE(filter(B3:D, B3:B=J1)))

Comment: oh sorry about that. Yes the solution works now. Thank you!